# How can i find my WPF Autocompletebox in my DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, datagrid, textbox

Hello I've been trying to integrate an Autocompletebox into my project for days, unfortunately without success. I'm getting a little desperate. I have at least found a very simple solution for a text box outside of my Datagrid (DotNetProjects.WpfToolkit.Input 6.0.90 https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetProjects.WpfToolkit.Input/) but I can't put it in my . I followed the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SK8TXvcPWqI. I will post my Code here:

```
<Grid>
<controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="ACB2" Text="TT" ></controls:AutoCompleteBox> 
</Grid>
```

This Box is working. I Can find the Box "ACB2" in my Code:

```
public Databasewindow()                                                  
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ACB2.FilterMode = AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains;
            ACB2.ItemsSource = new string[] { "TEST1", "TEST2 TEST2", "TEST3 TEST3" };

        }
```

But when i try to fill a Column and use this box i fail and cant find my Textbox anymore

```
<Grid>
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1"
    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="200" Header=" Command ">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <controls:AutoCompleteBox 
                                Text="{Binding Command, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                x:Name="ACB2" 
                                ></controls:AutoCompleteBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
           </DataGrid>
         </Grid>
```

The Binding Text="{Binding Command, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" is working good. But i cant find the x:Name="ACB2" in my Code anymore. Can anyone help me with this? I tried many different AutoCompleteFunctions (Nuget) but i always had problems with the suggestions-Bindings. Maybe someone has some experience with this and can can help me out? That would be very, very nice. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution for my Binding problem. Thank you Melkor V for your support. Here is my Code:

In my Xaml i had to add these lines for my Binding:

XAML:

```
xmlns:controls='clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=DotNetProjects.Input.Toolkit' xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Databases"
```

In my Datagrid => Commandselection is the Class where i wrote a List and AutoCompleteBoxItems is the Name of the List

```
<DataGrid 
   <DataGrid.DataContext>
         <local:Commandselection/>
   </DataGrid.DataContext>
</DataGrid>

<DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="200" Header=" Command ">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <controls:AutoCompleteBox 
                                Text="{Binding Command, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path = DataContext.AutoCompleteBoxItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                FilterMode="Contains" 
                                ></controls:AutoCompleteBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here is the Code of my Class:

```
class Commandselection 
    {

        public static ObservableCollection<string> AutoCompleteBoxItems { get; set; }
        public Commandselection()
        {
            AutoCompleteBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                "Apple",
                "Banana",
                "Carrot",
                "Dog",
                "Elderberry",
                "Fruit",
                "Grapes",
                "Honey",
                "Iron"
            };
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but I would tell you the simplest. Put x:Name to your DataGrid and get its first child so it would be your textbox. If you have smth more difficult to implement then look at MVVM and DataBinding... Its a long way of information to get but it is a right thing to know while working with WPF.

```
    public List<string> AutoCompleteBoxItems { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    
    public Databasewindow()                                                  
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        AutoCompleteBoxItems.Add("Test1");
        AutoCompleteBoxItems.Add("Test2");
    }
```

And XAML

```
        <controls:AutoCompleteBox Text="{Binding Command, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AutoCompleteBoxItems}"
FilterMode="Contains"></controls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Also you can use this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45956589/13134914) for find your UIElement but do that in DatGrid.Loaded event. You can always extend that method and find all same UIElements, but again thats not how you should do it. Use DataBinding insted. Strongly recommend.

Comment: Hello Melkor V, thank you for your reply. Can you give me an example? Kind regards

Comment: For this approach you need an ItemsSource property in your DataGrid. Another way to solve the problem is to bind ItemsSource for your AutoCompleteBox like: <controls:AutoCompleteBox 
                                Text="{Binding Command, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                x:Name="ACB2" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfItems}"
                                ></controls:AutoCompleteBox> Where CollectionOfItems is a collection with { "TEST1", "TEST2 TEST2", "TEST3 TEST3" } inside your DataBaseWindow as public property with get/set

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Tomorrow i will test it, when i am back at work again. You saved my day. When i have a problem at programming i cant stop thinking about it xD

Comment: @MarioAllw You'r welcome. Remember to mark an answer as accepted x)